# Stack project dependencies source code location

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Does stack save the project's dependencies source code? If so, where?

I've done a textual search in the project's `.stack-work/` but didn't find anything there.

Comment: The source tarballs are in `~/.stack/indices/Hackage/packages/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i remember correctly there are source files in `$HOME/.stack` somewhere, except for the packages listed in dependencies, those should be in your `.stack-work`.

But if you want to change some dependencies I would recommend putting those in a separate directory and put a reference to it in your packages section in the `stack.yaml`